# How to find out permission inherited sites in share point 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online

In our environment ,we have lot of site collections, subsites and sub-subsites .Their is a requirement to figure out the list of sites where it permissions getting inheritance from parent,and inheritance has to be stopped once list was outputted .

Do we have any script for this ?

THX

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below PowerShell script:

```
$siteUrl = "http://urlToYourSite"
$savePath = "c:\test\BrokenInheritanceReport.csv"

Get-SPSite $siteUrl  | 
  Get-SPWeb -Limit All | 
  Where { $_.HasUniquePerm -AND $_.ParentWeb -NE $Null } | 
  Select @{Label="Securable"; Expression={"Web"}}, 
         @{Label="Item"; Expression={$_.ServerRelativeUrl}}, 
         @{Label="Parent"; Expression={$_.ParentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl}} |
  Export-CSV $savePath

Get-SPSite $siteUrl  | 
  Get-SPWeb -Limit All | 
  Select -ExpandProperty Lists | 
  Where { $_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -AND -NOT $_.Hidden } | 
  Select @{Label="Securable"; Expression={"List"}}, 
         @{Label="Item"; Expression={$_.Title}}, 
         @{Label="Parent"; Expression={$_.ParentWebUrl}} |
  Export-CSV $savePath -Append

Get-SPSite $siteUrl  | 
  Get-SPWeb -Limit All | 
  Select -ExpandProperty Lists | 
  Where { -NOT $_.Hidden -AND $_.EntityTypeName -NE "PublishedFeedList" } | 
  Select -ExpandProperty Folders | 
  Where { $_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments } | 
  Select @{Label="Securable"; Expression={"Folder"}}, 
         @{Label="Item"; Expression={$_.Title}}, 
         @{Label="Parent"; Expression={$_.ParentList.ParentWebUrl + "/" +$_.ParentList.Title}} | 
  Export-CSV $savePath -Append

Get-SPSite $siteUrl  | 
  Get-SPWeb -Limit All | 
  Select -ExpandProperty Lists | 
  Where { -NOT $_.Hidden -AND $_.EntityTypeName -NE "PublishedFeedList" } | 
  Select -ExpandProperty Items | 
  Where { $_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments } | 
  Select @{Label="Securable"; Expression={"Item"}}, 
         @{Label="Item"; Expression={$_.Name}}, 
         @{Label="Parent"; Expression={$_.ParentList.ParentWebUrl + "/" +$_.ParentList.Title}} | 
  Export-CSV $savePath -Append


Import-CSV  $savePath | Sort Parent | Select *
# or open the CSV file in Excel and sort there.
```

Note:

- The above script is doing the opposite of what you are looking for, so just check the below condition to false, then you will get your report.
- In the above script check the condition like wherever you see 
  $*.HasUniquePerm or $*.HasUniqueRoleAssignments 
  Changed to

  if ($*.HasUniquePerm) -eq false) or $*.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq false)

Source:

[SharePoint PowerShell–Find all Broken Inheritance](https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2014/07/sharepoint-powershellfind-all-broken.html)

From the above script - you will get a CSV file for all sites those have been inherited from the parent, now write the below PowerShell code to stop inheritance to those sites:

**Stop site inheritance from the CSV report using PowerShell**

```
$sitesCSVPermissionInheriated = Import-CSV "c:\test\SiteInheritanceReport.csv" 

 Foreach ($oneSite in $sitesCSVPermissionInheriated )
 {


 if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)        
{            
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"      
 } 
#Get Site collection and open the web 
#$spSite = Get-SPSite "http://servername/sites/TestYogesh" 
#$spSiteUrl = Read-Host "Enter the site url" 
#$spSite = Get-SPWeb $spSiteUrl 
 $spSite=Get-SPWeb $oneSite.SiteURL
If ($spsite.IsRootWeb -eq $true)     
{ 
$spWeb = $spSite 
Write-Host ($spSite.Url + "This is the Site collection") 
# To delete existing permissions presee yes 
$yes = Read-Host  
"Enter Yes to delete existing permissions on site collections" 
if($yes -eq "Yes")         
{ 
       # Remove unnecessary groups/users from the site permissions        
     for ($i = 0; $i -le $spWeb.RoleDefinitions.Count; $i++)                    
     {                     
        $spWeb.RoleDefinitions.Delete($i)                
         }  
       } 
   } 
else 
{ 
$spweb = Get-SPWeb $spSiteUrl  
If ( ($spWeb.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -and $spWeb.HasUniqueRoleDefinitions) -eq $false ) 
 {      
$spWeb.RoleDefinitions.BreakInheritance($true, $true)  
#$spWeb.BreakRoleInheritance($true,$true)  
$spWeb.Update() Write-Host ($spSite.Url + "Inheritance is Just broken")              
# Remove unnecessary groups/users from the site permissions    
         for ($i = 0; $i -le $spWeb.RoleDefinitions.Count; $i++)   
          {            $spWeb.RoleDefinitions.Delete($i)           
      }  
} else 
 {  
Write-Host ($spSite.Url + "Inheritance is already broken")  
   # Remove unnecessary groups/users from the site permissions             
for ($i = 0; $i -le $spWeb.RoleDefinitions.Count; $i++)           
  { 
            $spWeb.RoleDefinitions.Delete($i)       
      }             
 } 
} 
$spWeb.Dispose() 
$spsite.Dispose()


 }
```

Source of the script:

[SharePoint 2013: Break Site Permissions Inheritance using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/To-break-the-original-8a18e0fa)